# Sort a 2-D array in Java based on one parameter first and then based on the second. [JAVA]

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Let's say I have a 2-D array `arr[][]`:

```
col1 col2
[1, 7]
[2, 6]
[3, 9]
[4, 1]
[5, 3]
[6, 7]
```

and we have to sort it based on `col1` 1st and then based on `col2`

What is the way to do this in Java? Particularly how can we use comparator to achieve the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to the following using comparator would be:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> a[0] != b[0] ? a[0]-b[0] : a[1]-b[1]);
```

Or to simplify, if `arr[row1][col0]` **is not equal** to `arr[row2][col0]`, then sort it by `col0` and **if they are equal** then sort it by `col2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using comparator chaining:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(arr1 -> arr1[0]).thenComparing(arr1 -> arr1[1]));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```